# Windows Phone Store Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation

At the moment there is no tag for the windows phone store.

There is a rather complicated review process for getting an app accepted to the phone store, this is all things that are on-topic, and are related specifically to QA aspects of the store and the review process.

I've noticed that all the questions related don't have a tag when I wanted to search for them.

Today [**I asked a WP8 store question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685889/windows-phone-scan-the-app-for-malware) and used my tag creation priviledge to create a tag for windows phone store.

A high reputation user edited the tag out and removed it, so some people (obviously) don't agree that a [windows-phone-store](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-store) should exist. I figured the right thing to do is to open it for meta discussion.

- Should there be a Windows Phone 8 Store tag? Why?

Comment: Was it Charles? :) Best approach would be to find a couple of questions that need the tag and to edit all of them. And give the wiki a bit of material. Then it's less likely to be deleted.

Comment: I almost removed it earlier (and voted to close your question)... I think the tag is appropriate for the question but I'm less certain that the question is appropriate for the site. It was a close call.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if the review process is a topic for the site. Not really sure.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Why? It's a specific question relating to an actual  programming problem I'm facing as a developer. It's applicable to the developer crowd, it's not opinion based, and it has a simple answer (hopefully).

Comment: You're skirting the "how do I upload my app to the app store" territory, except you've asked it a lot better than most of them. The difference is with your question that it obviously doesn't make sense and it's the documentation that's at fault... as I said it was a close call and I _didn't_ vote to close :-).

Comment: For the protocol, I asked in a facebook group and they told me that I'm supposed to scan the app with windows defender. I don't really trust their advice, I really don't want to fail certification because iterations could take weeks.

Comment: @Bart, oh ye of little faith, it was a new tag, and it got deleted, *of course* it was me!  So actually, I think I intended to replace it with one the Windows Store tags, but spaced on it.  Is there an *actual* difference between the Windows Store bits and the Windows Store bits in the context of Windows Phone 8 applications?

Comment: @Charles Yes, the store is different, the QA criteria is different and acceptance is different. Windows Store answers are pretty much useless as a filter for windows phone stuff and even worse, because there is no tag they show up in google searches - the keywords are similar (windows and store, and people talking about phoning Microsoft or their customers about things), this makes looking for WP store answers even _harder_. (Yes, I'm looking at you people in Microsoft that name things - it used to have a distinct name (marketplace) but for some reason they decided to change it).

Comment: If anyone ever calls you unreliable @Charles, send them to me. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think such a tag should exist for the following reasons.

- The **Microsoft documentation** system MSDN has **very bad** SEO (I've discussed it with their developer relations), it's very had to find related material on it. For instance the question I asked today got a decent amount of views and upvotes but no answers yet.
- It's **sufficiently different** from other windows phone 8 questions. It's a different group of questions specifically related to the APIs related to the store, how they work, and how to get past the review process.
- It  would have **saved me time** before. I wanted to do a tag search looking for store acceptance QA answers.

My question is not the only one there:

- [How to run Windows Phone Store Cetrification Kit from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958824/how-to-run-windows-phone-store-cetrification-kit-from-command-line)
- [How to get Windows app store dev center data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912624/how-to-get-windows-phone-store-dev-centre-data)
- [how to use Windows phone store test kit in Windows Phone 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698029/how-to-use-windows-phone-store-test-kit-in-windows-phone-7-1)
- [Submit "Test notes" or "instructions WP8 app submission - Where can I find them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131738/submit-test-notes-or-instructions-wp8-app-submission-where-can-i-find-them)
- [Continuous integration for Windows 8 Store Application with Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749176/continuous-integration-for-windows-8-store-application-with-jenkins)